# Copy and paste using last row, Error 91

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, copy-paste

I am trying to copy and paste a range of values based on the last row in the range, meaning that the number of rows will vary but the number of columns will all ways stay the same.

The code I have written to do this continues to return the error :

> Object Variable or With Block Variable not set

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

```
Sub update()

Dim LR As Range
Dim Revise As Range

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

Set Revise = Range("M1:M" & LR)

Revise.Copy

Sheets(Weekly).Select
Cells(1,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll


End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that :

- you defined `LR` as `Range` which is an object
- you are trying to assign a value to it, without using `Set` keyword (like for `Set Revise`)
- If you add `Set`, you'd have an Error 13 because you are trying to put a number into a Range! ;)

Corrected code :

```
Sub update()
    Dim LR As Double
    Dim SrcWS As Worksheet
    Set SrcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With SrcWS
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("M1:M" & LR).Copy
    End With 'SrcWS 

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly").Cells(1,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

Comment: I am now getting a runtime error "out of range" I switched the sub up to copy from column "I" to column "M" And I am now getting the out of range error. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: @Reisenrich : Glad I could help! ;)

Comment: @Reisenrich : How about accepting my answer then? :)

Comment: Sorry, got lost in updating my spread sheet (: Still having an issue with the "out of Range" error. When debuging it appears to have issue with the paste command

Comment: @Reisenrich verify that your sheet names don't have leading/trailing spaces. "Out of range" is very likely to be because there is no sheet named "Weekly" in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: You sir are a WIZARD. Thank you!

Comment: @Mat'sMug : Yes, you are! ;) Thx for answering the OP! BTW, may I have your opinion on this : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/157336/71125    0:)

Answer (score 0):

There's some code you have... You need to work more on your skills... Try the following:

```
Sub update()

    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Revise As Range
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Revise = Range("M1:M" & LR)
    Revise.Copy
    Sheets("Weekly").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End sub
```

Comment: You should use `Long` or `Double` instead of `Integer` for `LR`, because `Integer` is limited to 32k (and a little something more), but try `LR = 33000` and you'll have an error due to `Integer` ;)

Comment: Yes, I know... However didn't think of that... Usually I only remember that tiny detail when I'm working with big excel tables and the code generates an error... And then... "Oh s****! Forgot the long thing again!!!" Eh eh... Thanks for the reminder... :)